# A command for change prefix

Tags: command, bots, discord, discord.js

I want to make a command like `y!prefix [new_prefix]` for servers who add my bot.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to make a json file to stock the prefix.
Next, make a command with this :

```
    let prefixes = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./JSON/prefix.json", "utf8"));

    prefixes[message.guild.id] = {
        prefixes: args[0]
    };

    fs.writeFile("./JSON/prefix.json", JSON.stringify(prefixes), (err) => {
        if(err) console.log(err);
    });
```

After, you just have to set the prefix for your commands in your main with something like this :

```
let prefixes = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./JSON/prefix.json", "utf8"));

  if (!prefixes[message.guild.id]) {
    prefixes[message.guild.id] = {
      prefixes: PREFIX,
    };
  }

  let gprefix = prefixes[message.guild.id].prefixes;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I use glitch. And i have a lot of errors for "fs" etc.

Comment: If I remember, Glitch can't be use with ``fs`` because it can't write on your files. If you want to use Glitch you will have to use a database like MongoDB for example.

Comment: I use glutch for host my bot.  Mongo does that?

Comment: MongoDB is a database, so with MongoDB it will save it on MongoDB and not on your files on glitch.

Comment: How can I install it?